# Emulator in VSCODE for SWIFT language

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, visual-studio-code

Could i get an iPhone emulator? I started to programming in swift in vscode and i am using Windows 10.
Any help?

[image: 1]

Comment: You will need a Mac or access to a Mac.

Comment: thank for answer, @Paulw11

Comment: Or you can use VM on Windows (I am assuming you're on Windows), set Mac OS as an OS, Then install Xcode. From there, You can build apps now :)